# Setting up 2nd LAN on pfSense

Tags: local-area-network, pfsense

I have a working pfSense router with DSL PPPoE on the WAN, and a bunch of devices connected to the LAN, using 192.168.2.X.  The pfSense box itself is at 192.168.2.1, and acts as a DHCP server and DNS server.

I have another NIC in the pfSense box that I want to use for a second LAN with a different subnet (such as 192.168.3.X).

I can set up the OPT1 interface and give it an 192.168.3.1 address, but not sure how to specify so that the pfSense box (at 192.168.2.1) will be the DNS server - let alone a DHCP server for the 3.X network.

Is this possible?